# Postgresql - Stored Procedure that returns a table result set

Tags: postgresql

Im new to PostgreSQL v.13 and want to create a Stored Procedure that will receive an integer value and then return the results from a table.

I have this:

```
create or replace procedure public.sp_message_template_get(
   templateid int
)  language plpgsql AS $$
   
      
begin
    -- subtracting the amount from the sender's account 
 select * from public.message_template;

    --commit;
end;
$$
```

Then I try to call it by using:

```
call public.sp_message_template_get(1);
```

And I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function sp_message_template_get(integer) line 6 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Stored procedures cannot return things. If you want to do that use a function. See [Returning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) 43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY. FYI,  you got the error message  because you ran a `SELECT` and did not capture the results. To do that you need to use [PERFORM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL) 43.5.2. Executing SQL Commands

Comment: I was confused because in MS SQL Server you normally use SP to return values, so in PostgreSQL you have to use functions instead? So what’s the purpose of SP?

Comment: @VAAA Well, Postgres is different then SQL Server, and in Postgres you need to use a function if to return something. You need to [migrate your mindset too](http://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/)

Comment: See [Procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.html). The primary benefit of a procedure is that you can do transaction management inside it. For most things you probably want to use a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sql function.

```sql
create or replace function message_template_get(templateid integer)
returns setof message_template language sql as
$$
  -- subtracting the amount from the sender's account (sql query)
  select * from public.message_template;
$$;
```

If there is a reason to use plpgsql language then use `return query`.

```sql
create or replace function message_template_get(templateid integer)
returns setof message_template language plpgsql as
$$
begin
  -- subtracting the amount from the sender's account
  return query select * from public.message_template;
  -- maybe other statements here
end;
$$;
```

Please note that `commit` is not necessary and illegal in a function body. More than one `return query` or `return next` statements are possible.